# Как сделать поочередную загрузку данных с помощью kotlin coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, rxjava2

С помощью rxjava в классе репозитория я делал так:

```
private val scheduler = Schedulers.single()
fun callApiMethod(args):Single<ResultType>{
    return apiMethod(args).subscribeOn(scheduler)
}
```

Как я понял в классе viewmodel'и нужно сделать так:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    val result = callApiMethod(args) //функция должна быть suspend и вовзращать ResultType
    //Обновление livedata
}
```

Как переписать это на корутины?

Answer (score 0):

Функция которую вы будете вызывать внутри корутины должна иметь модификатор suspend. Если вы используете Retrofit для него можно подключить CoroutineCallAdapter

```
addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())

val parentJob : Job =Job() 
val yourCoroutineScope:  CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(parentJob + Dispatchers.IO) 

yourCoroutineScope.launch {
    val result = callApiMethod(args:Args)
}
```

Comment: а разве нельзя без coroutine call adapter? просто написать suspend у метода в интерфейсе: suspend fun apiMethod(args):Response<ResultType>?

Comment: извиняюсь, уже понял, в чем преимущество

Comment: Попробовал применить ваш подход, не очень понял одну вещь: в viewmodel я вызываю viewModelScope.launch { myRepository.callApiMethod(args) //и дальше обновляю livedata}. В классе репозитория функция callApiMethod возвращает ResultType и она suspend. Как мне сделать return result внутри launch?

Comment: Используете async тогда вместо launch. Если я конечно вас правильно понял. А если у вас ещё и ViewModel то делайте post прямо в корутине.

Comment: сделал так: return withContext(coroutineScope.coroutineContext) {
            return@withContext myResult
        }, где coroutineScope это yourCoroutineScope из вашего примера, но всё-равно оно не выполняет главное требование: поочередная загрузка

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/344016/ вот здесь schedulers.single() найдите, если непонятно что я хочу получить

Comment: странно кстати что val dispatcher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher() и withContext(dispatcher) не работает последовательно